# Sort Groups by name in XtraReport

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I am making a report that has several groups. Each group represents an object, and in each group the details for the object is listed in a DetailBand.

However, I can not find a way to sort the groups so that they are ordered on the report based on the name of the of the objects. I have read documentation from DevExpress that explains how to sort groups by summary functions, and how to sort within a DetailBand, but this is not helpful for my situation.

The (very) basic structure of my report is like this:

- Report

  - DetailReportBand

    - GroupHeaderBand (want to order by this)
    - DetailBand

Any help is appreciated :)

**Edit**: I am doing this in code.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Group and Sort option you have to first add the field you wish to group by as a sort on the report and then tick the option Show Header, this will automatically create the group header for you and sort via that group.

If you have already created the group header band you can just copy and paste the fields into the new band and then delete the existing group header band.

Comment: Thans for response James. However I am doing this in code. Do you know how to do it there?

Comment: I'm afraid i dont know how to do it in code, however i presume it will be the same functionality, sort the data first and then create the group header?

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting this same battle today.  I've found that in my case I had to set the `SortingSummary.FieldName` property to the name of the field to sort on, which in my case is different than the name of the field I'm grouping on.

The name of my GroupHeaderBand is QuestionsGroup.  I am grouping on a field called "GroupName", but I want the groups sorted by "LineNumber".  In code, I have this:

```
QuestionsGroup.SortingSummary.FieldName = "LineNumber";

GroupFields.Add(new GroupField("GroupName"));
```

Also, make sure that the `GroupHeaderBand.SortingSummary.Enabled = true`.  I had previously set the Function to Custom, and that was not working so I arbitrarily changed it to Avg and now it's working.

Good Luck!